# Adding xml to DOMElement from String

Tags: java, dom4j

I have a string with xml content, for example:

```
String str = "<history><message from="Alice" to="Bob" /></history>";
```

and I want to add this xml content to some element (org.dom4j.DOMElement).
How to do it?

I've tried this:

```
myElement.addText(str);
```

But it gives me just escaped text content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Dom4j to parse the XML fragment into a separate Document object, and then append the root element of that Document object to the appropriate place of your target Document.